# Non-Standard Characters Cause Line to Appear in Hexadecimal

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have recently moved from a classic Linux server (using phpMyAdmin 3.3.5) to a cPanel server (using phpMyAdmin 4.0.10) and after multiple attempts was able to import my MediaWiki database. However, I noticed any value that contained non-English characters (Japanese letters or other symbols) appeared entirely in hexadecimal. I have tried pasting in a non-hex equivalent to a hex line, but the result is in 0 lines changing and the value changing back to hexadecimal.

[Example of working names on the previous server, seen with values "KrzesłaKonferencyjne" and "Zgłoszenie szkody warta".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjgIr.png)

[Example of non-working names on the current server, seen with values "4b727a6573c582614b6f6e666572656e63796a6e65" and "5a67c5826f737a656e696520737a6b6f6479207761727461".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OihtP.png)

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: What was the old server encoding, and what is the new server encoding?  They need to be the same.  I recommend UTF8 as a start, possibly moving to UTF32 if needed.

Comment: The old server used a latin1 collation for the specific database I had dumped, but a universal collation of utf8_unicode_ci. The new server has a universal charset of UTF-8 Unicode as well, but the new server's collation for my database was, if I recall correctly, changed manually from a latin collation. With this in mind, would changing the collation of the old database to UTF8, then re-exporting and re-importing the database likely cure the bug?

Comment: [update: have tried changing the original collation, nothing has changed. Trying to upload the file as a MediaWiki Table has resulted in nothing showing up, ruling that out as an option.]